# Why is the JLabel not following the GridLayout and how to remove the gap in between?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, imageicon

My application here is about piecing up a whole image made up of six individual pieces. I declared them as `JLabels` and set the layout using `GridLayout`. However, the `JLabels` are not following the rows and columns given and there are gaps in between.

Do you think I have a wrong coding here somewhere?
Thanks!

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Color;

class MyGridLayout extends JPanel {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    JFrame pictureFrame = new JFrame("Picture Frame");
    GridLayout myGrid = new GridLayout(2, 3, 0, 0);
    pictureFrame.setLayout(myGrid);

    MyGridLayout thePanel = new MyGridLayout();
    pictureFrame.add(thePanel);

    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("IMAGES/chunkE.gif");
    ImageIcon j = new ImageIcon("IMAGES/chunkC.gif");
    ImageIcon k = new ImageIcon("IMAGES/chunkB.gif");
    ImageIcon l = new ImageIcon("IMAGES/chunkI.gif");

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel(i);
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(j);
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel(k);
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel(l);

    thePanel.add(label1);
    thePanel.add(label2);
    thePanel.add(label3);
    thePanel.add(label4);

    pictureFrame.add(thePanel); 
    pictureFrame.pack();
    pictureFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pictureFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: @peeskillet hey hi thanks so much for your editting. how did you do it and what was it for? Cheers!

Comment: I just added the code highlighting. You can surround code with backticks ( **`** ) to highlight your code. To edit in general, you just click the edit link at the bottom of your post. You can see the edit history by clicking on the link that say "edit X days ago". It just how we help the community's questions/posts stay clean.

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: @peeskillet oic but when you highlight the code, what does it do actually? does it help say when other search in the search engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the layout of `JPanel` instead of `JFrame`

```
GridLayout myGrid = new GridLayout(2, 3, 0, 0);
thePanel.setLayout(myGrid);
```

[JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) by default uses [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html)

Comment: Cool! Thanks so much for your help and your explanation makes me understand why it doesn't work. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Main extends JFrame
{
    public Main()
    {
        super("Title");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3);

        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("IMAGES/chunkE.gif");
        ImageIcon j = new ImageIcon("IMAGES/chunkC.gif");
        ImageIcon k = new ImageIcon("IMAGES/chunkB.gif");
        ImageIcon l = new ImageIcon("IMAGES/chunkI.gif");

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(i);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(j);
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(k);
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel(l);

        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(label3);
        panel.add(label4);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main m = new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: @j-B thanks for helping as well mate I have managed to correct my error already cheers!